# I'm trying to display an pdf located in a tomcat server on my angular application

Tags: angular, tomcat9

I am having a problem displaying a pdf doc that I have stored in my tomcat 9 server (ex: //tomcat/pdf/mypdf.pdf).

So I managed to stocket my pdf in my server and to retrieve my url and store it in my database, when I retrieve the link that I have stocket in my database and I paste it on a browser it displays my pdf with file in front :
file://///tomcat/pdf/mypdf.pdf.
And I try to display this image by retrieving this url from my database and displaying it as is in a href :
ex:--> (I use angular)
I made a console.log of my attachment and I do have the url retrieved from the database, but it doesn't work.

I don't know how to solve this problem, as I don't really know how to access server data. I thought it would work as I do it, but obviously not.

Could someone help me?

Comment: Do you have any errors on the browser console? It is unusual to have the URL of a download be from `file://`, which directly accesses the current computer's file system. Other people visiting your server won't have that file. Use a URL with the hostname. If external access is needed, search for that on StackOverflow (for example [How to access tomcat server from outside network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76969899/how-to-access-tomcat-server-from-outside-network))

Comment: Can you add a code snippet on how you are trying to access pdf or errors that you have?

Comment: I think I mistyped how to display an image/pdf located on my srv-tomcat.

I think that to display my image/pdf on my angular front, I have to reload the image? My back must be able to send a file which will allow me to display it?
I thought I could directly display my image/pdf if I store the path to access it in the database.